# How to delete xmlns="" tag from XQuery result?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I'm making an XQuery on a java code that generates a file extracting data from two different xml files from eXistDB, but when I generate the output xml it adds xmlns="" tag on every child element.

This is the output xml that i'm getting:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<produc>
    <cod_prod xmlns="">1011</cod_prod>
    <denominación xmlns="">Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominación>
    <precio xmlns="">120</precio>
    <nombre_zona xmlns="">Madrid-CENTRO</nombre_zona>
    <director xmlns="">Pedro Martín</director>
    <stock xmlns="">-2</stock>
</produc>
<produc>
    <cod_prod xmlns="">1019</cod_prod>
    <denominación xmlns="">Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 2GB</denominación>
    <precio xmlns="">10</precio>
    <nombre_zona xmlns="">Madrid-CENTRO</nombre_zona>
    <director xmlns="">Pedro Martín</director>
    <stock xmlns="">2</stock>
</produc>
<produc>
    <cod_prod xmlns="">1020</cod_prod>
    <denominación xmlns="">Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 4GB</denominación>
    <precio xmlns="">30</precio>
    <nombre_zona xmlns="">Madrid-CENTRO</nombre_zona>
    <director xmlns="">Pedro Martín</director>
    <stock xmlns="">20</stock>
</produc>
```

This is the XQuery used to generate the output:

```
consulta = conn.prepareExpression("for $prod in //produc[cod_zona="+zona+"] " +
                    "let $nombre_zona:=//zona[cod_zona = $prod/cod_zona]/nombre " + 
                    "let $director:=//zona[cod_zona = $prod/cod_zona]/director " + 
                    "return" + 
                    "   <produc>" + 
                    "   <cod_prod>{data($prod/cod_prod)}</cod_prod> " + 
                    "   <denominación>{data($prod/denominacion)}</denominación> " + 
                    "   <precio>{data($prod/precio)}</precio> " + 
                    "   <nombre_zona>{data($nombre_zona)}</nombre_zona> " + 
                    "   <director>{data($director)}</director> " + 
                    "   <stock>{data($prod/stock_actual)-data($prod/stock_minimo)}</stock> " + 
                    "   </produc>"
                    );
```

Comment: Is the shown output sample the complete output you get? Can you show us minimal but complete samples of an XML input, the Java code to run the query and output the query results, to allow us to reproduce the problem? Also as you use a particular software like eXist, it would help if you tell us the exact version you use.

Comment: That is not an attribute niether a *"tag"*. It's a namespace declaration. In particular, that is the default namespace declaration binding the default namespace to the empty namespace. In general, that declaration is not neeeded unless there is other default namespace declaration up at the hierarchy. Because  an XML document is invalid if there are more than one document element (ie. more that one `produc`), I suspect there is some fragment of the document you didn't show us.